# Run PNPM install in a specific path

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, pnpm

I have a PNPM workspace with NX on top of it, my project architecture is like the following:

```
├── package.json (global package.json)
├── nx.json (global nx config)
├── apps
│   ├── APP1
│   │   ├── package.json (private package.json)
│   │   ├── src/ (src folder)
│   │   ├── scripts/esbuild.js
│   ├── ... (other apps)
└── packages
    ├── common
    │   ├── package.json (private package.json)
│   │   ├── src/ (src folder)
    ├── ... (other shared libs)
```

The APP1 needs to be built for a AWS lambda deployment (which requires having the bundled js files and the production node_modules inside of layers/node).

I have this script in the APP1 package.json

```
"build": "node ./scripts/esbuild.js"
```

esbuild.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const { build } = require('esbuild');
const glob = require('glob');

const { nodeExternalsPlugin } = require('esbuild-node-externals');
const { esbuildDecorators } = require('esbuild-plugin-ts-decorators');

const Execa = require('execa');
const { Listr } = require('listr2');

const isCI = process.argv.includes('--ci');

// default export should be an array of plugins
const plugins = [
  nodeExternalsPlugin(),
  esbuildDecorators({
    cache: true,
  }),
];

const entryPoints = [...glob.sync('./src/main.ts')];
const outDir = `../.dist/src`;

const root = path.join(__dirname, '..');

const esbuildFunction = async () => {
  await build({
    entryPoints,
    bundle: true,
    outdir: path.join(__dirname, outDir),
    platform: 'node',
    sourcemap: 'external',
    target: ['es2017', 'node14'],
    logLevel: 'info',
    watch: process.argv.includes('--watch'),
    plugins,
  });
};

const tasksList = [
  {
    title: '[BUILD] - Clean up',
    task: async (ctx, task) => {
      const subprocess = Execa('rm', ['-r', `${root}/.dist`]);
      if (subprocess.stdout) subprocess.stdout.pipe(task.stdout());
      try {
        await subprocess;
      } catch (e) {}
    },
  },
  {
    title: '[BUILD] - esbuild',
    task: async (ctx, task) => {
      await esbuildFunction();
    },
  },
  {
    title: '[BUILD] - Modules: Layers - copy package.json',
    task: async (ctx, task) => {
      const subprocess = Execa('cp', ['package.json', `${root}/.dist`]);
      if (subprocess.stdout) subprocess.stdout.pipe(task.stdout());
      await subprocess;
    },
  },
  {
    title: '[BUILD] - Modules: Install node_modules',
    task: async (ctx, task) => {
      const baseDirectory = `${root}/.dist`;
      const nodeModulesPath = `${baseDirectory}/layers/nodejs`;

      try {
        await Execa('mkdir', ['-p', nodeModulesPath]);
      } catch (e) {}
      await Execa('cp', [`${baseDirectory}/package.json`, nodeModulesPath]);

      const subprocess = Execa('pnpm', ['install', '--prod'], { cwd: nodeModulesPath });


      if (subprocess.stdout) subprocess.stdout.pipe(task.stdout());
      await subprocess;
    },
  },
];

const tasks = new Listr(tasksList, { concurrent: false });

const run = async () => {
  await tasks.run();
};

run();
```

The `Execa('pnpm', ['install', '--prod'], { cwd: nodeModulesPath });` is supposed to install the packages of the copied package.json file inside of .dist/layers/node. This doesn't work, and instead it's installing the packages in the root of the APP1. However In NPM something like `npm install --prefix folder ...` is working.
Any solution on how can I do this ? (install pnpm packages in a certain path, maybe baypassing the workspace ?)